# Deskop shows green dots and skip some letter after upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, release-management, 20.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, software looks working fine, but the main GNOME desktop screen is showing these green lines. Also Gedit text icon in the Dock has some buggy look and some characters are missing in upper clock as seen in the below screenshot. In Ubuntu 19.10 everything worked fine. When the screen image changes the green lines disappear, but after rebooting they come back again.

[image: as seen in screenshot]

If I don't find out how to fix it, I'll have to downgrade back to Ubuntu 19.10. I am disappointed, because this is the first problem I've had with Ubuntu after four years of using it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231002/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

That is the exact same issue I'm having. Wasn't an issue before the upgrade to 20.04. I don't see any errors being logged that relates to this issue.

Switching to Wayland solves the issue. Logging out and using Xorg, I have the exact same issue again. Are you by any chance on a Dell XPS? I've seen a few graphical issues with Ubuntu 20.04 on XPS (only when upgrading, not on fresh installs) and most of them have be solved by switching to Wayland.

Comment: I have not try Wayland but reinstalling it from LiveUSB worked. I habe been upgrading via do-release-upgrade command, so maybe there they have an issue. You can make it work throught reinstalling, but you will lose most of your programs and be careful about efi partitionit from older versions. This helped me.

Comment: I also upgraded using `do-release-upgrade`. 
Seems to be related to xserver-xorg-video-intel according to this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1242088/449635

Once removed, it fixed my issues.