# Graphical glitches after updating from 19.10 to 20.04 on Dell XPS 9370

Tags: drivers, updates, graphics, dell, 20.04

Today I've updated to 20.04 from 19.10 by getting the latest updates and doing a sudo do-release-upgrade -d after that.
After booting the lockscreen looks fine but after logging in it presents me with some graphical glitches that are different on every boot(2 different ones shown below).
The green bars are also not visible while in a browser so it seems to be stuck to the background and the UI icons only for some reason.
There are no new package updates available that could be a potential fix.

[image: graphical glitches 1]
[image: graphical glitches 2]

I'm on a 13 inch Dell XPS 9370(so Intel UHD 620 graphics).
Haven't had a flawless Ubuntu OS update so far since I've started using it a few years ago. Last time I fixed it by doing a fresh install of the new version but I really want to see if I can fix it without that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C display` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230804/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)