# 20.04 - Screen problem (vertical green lines)

Tags: video, 20.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, my screen has now two vertical green lines (Here a screenshot of my desktop:

[image: nlinn]

Does anyone know why is that and how I can get rid of them?

In case: my video cards are

VGA compatible controller: Intel UHD Graphics 630 (mobile)
3D controller: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]

Machine: Dell XPS 15 9570

Comment: Upload the pic to https://imgur.com or some other open hosting site, then click [edit] and put the link to the uploaded pic in your question. And, there are many, many 15" Dell PCs. What's the model part number from the serial number or service tag sticker? That gives us useful info.

Comment: Are Nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: Yes: Nvidia drivers are installed.

I added the link to the screenshot of my desktop and the details about the machine. The serial number is not written on the machine: it is probably inside somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I have the same cards. For me the artifacts took the form of green squares scattered across my background, and corrupted icons. `apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still looking and I seem to have found a solution ... see this thread.
[Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)
when using the code

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

At least it worked for me and I no longer have broken graphics on my multi-PGU machine.

Answer (score 0):

I join the interviewer and follow this thread. I have the same problem.
I have a machine with a multi-GPU = integrated Intel HD Graphics 630, a dedicated 7x NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti.
Since I only use nVidia for CUDA calculations, the display is sent to Intel HD - by editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "intel"
Screen 1 "nvidia1"
EndSection
Section "Device"
Identifier "intel"
Driver "intel"
BusID "PCI:00:02:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
Identifier "intel"
Device "intel"
EndSection
Section "Device"
Identifier "nvidia1"
Driver "nvidia"
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
Identifier "nvidia1"
Device "nvidia1"
EndSection
```