# Glitches after update 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04

[image]

It is getting worse, please help!

Comment: Have you checked the drivers in the `Software & Updates` app? What graphics card are you using?

Comment: solved `sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` https://askubuntu.com/a/1233403/1038028