# Choppy graphics performance on Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, intel-graphics, gui

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T480. For some reason, I am getting several issues. The two most irritating are a "ripping" screen effect when an animated transition takes place, and the laptop frequently forgetting resolution/dual monitor display settings and freezing when I try to reset them. Another issue I am getting sometimes is a black screen with a cursor after logging in and then the desktop interface doesn't show up. All in all - the experience just feels a little bit choppy and considerably more sluggish than on my Windows installation. In fact, when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my powerful gaming desktop pc (Ryzen 3700X, GeForce RTX 2070, 32GB RAM, NVME SSDs) it still felt equally choppy.

The GPU inside the laptop is an Intel UHD 620. I have downloaded the intel-gpu-tools .deb file from their website, but I'm not actually sure how to use the tools or whether the issues I am having are to do with the graphics driver or not.

I am wondering if anyone else is facing the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 on a powerful machine, and whether anybody can suggest an easy way to install the latest graphics drivers for my GPU, and see if that fixes it.

EDIT: Added output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
'lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' 00:02.0 
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)   
Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)   
Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Yes and no. My system feels (slightly) nippier in some aspects, but I still notice screen tearing if I (say) drag a window and move it around in circles. Also, is there a way to increase the refresh rate of the visuals (to 60Hz) so that it feels much smoother like it would on my Windows machine?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Similar problem with Lenovo Yoga X390 (Intel 620 on i915 drivers). 

'`'lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915`

The problem persists with external 4k display connected via Thunderbolt Dock. On 19.04 it seemed to be more smooth. Any ideas on how to optimise it is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just did this now. Sorry for taking so long.