# Blurry lines across screen

Tags: 20.04, display

I have just started using Ubuntu and there are four horizontal, blurry lines on the screen. The lines are not present on windows.

Ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS

Processor: AMD® A10-6700 APU with Radeon(TM) HD graphics × 4

Comment: There are a number of helpful references available but does this one help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04 or this one? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-display-fuzzy.html.en

Comment: Please expand your question and add a screenshot to show the issue along with specifications of your machine ... to make it easier to identify for members who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the clock and screen position in my monitor settings.