# Ubuntu 20.4 LTS upgrade graphical glitches

Tags: 20.04, graphics

I updated from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and now my Desktop and the text in the toolbar have weird graphical glitches (see screenshot). They different every time I restart.

Does somebody have an idea what could be the problem and where I should start looking? My first guess would be that some module got removed accidentally but I wouldn't know which one.

I also tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`.

#### Edit

```
xxx:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
DeviceName: Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing the correct drivers to the videocard? Or, alternatively if You already have the correct drivers; have you tried to go to software-updates (I think it's in the terminal called `gtk-software-properties`) and Checked there if you can choose (at the Drivers tab) some other Drivers?

**related:**

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612018/ubuntu-20-04-problems-with-interface-after-installation

**Edit:**

> I don't know if this will work; but if you're ok with re-installing
> gnome (As I said above: I am Not sure if this will work, so if unsure I would
> not try this, mainly because you can still access the desktop,
> somehow.)

however If you want to re-install gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

[Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)

The answer from:

[Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04/1233403#1233403)

`sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`

> "Reboot and everything is back being normal."

Edit2:

Related:
[Why is my monitor glitching out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281146/why-is-my-monitor-glitching-out)

Comment: Thank you! A comment in the related link led me to the answer. If you want to edit your answer accordingly, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll accept mine below in a few days.

Comment: @Snowbunting Yeah sure, of course I will edit,  can you provide me the exact comment?

Comment: @Snowbunting I maybe misunderstood;  Did you mean I shall edit my answer  from your answer? (The  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop  ) (Sorry I am new to this) Thanks, again!

Comment: I meant if you include my answer, I'll accept yours and give you the points ;)

Comment: Oh - right Thanks,   I'm as said still new, but thanks for having patience,  Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

This has been solved [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233403/1133186).

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

followed by a reboot and everything is back to normal.