# Why is my monitor glitching out?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I have a dual monitor display with some pretty aged monitors. Recently, however, my secondary display has begun glitching out whenever I first turn it on for the day. Everything (except the mouse) maps to the display permanently, until something goes over it. I don't really understand what's happening. When I restart my computer, the glitch disappears. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Glitch]

Output of `lscpi | grep VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430]'
```

The monitor having the problem is connected via a VGA cable. The other one (not having the problem) is connected through a DVI-VGA adapter.

Does anyone know what's going on, or how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of video card is the secondary video monitor connected to, and with what kind of cable (VGA, DVI, HDMI, etc.)? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question with the information you requested.

Comment: Did you recently update your Ubuntu, maybe to 20.04? It looks like the AMD/ATI video driver needs an update. You can prove this by swapping monitors, since they both use VGA.

Comment: Could you try the fix(es) from this post?
from  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279996/ubuntu-20-4-lts-upgrade-graphical-glitches/1280002#1280002

Comment: @heynnema The only version of Ubuntu I have ever installed on this computer is 20.04. I haven't updated from any past versions.

Comment: Try swapping the monitors, and update the video driver. Report back.