# How to turn off fix Ubuntu UI issues?

Tags: drivers, unity, graphics

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 (dual booted with Windows) happily for a year. Recently, I didn't run Ubuntu for a week and was using Windows for long. Then I booted up Ubuntu and I started finding weird behavior at some places.

1. There were weird graphics glitches at some places ([full screen snap](https://i.postimg.cc/8km6Q2Nn/Screenshot-from-2022-08-20-15-13-54.png)):
   [image]
2. VLC player videos play fine but its menus respond late. That is, when hovered, they get highlighted late.
3. Brave and chromium browser were super slow. Edge browser was fine buts is Developer tools were also super slow. It was also showing such weird graphics:
   [image]
4. To all fix this, I updated Ubuntu through Software Updater. (I never ever upated anything at all earlier in Ubuntu) But after update and restart, the UI become even worst as can be seen in [this](https://i.postimg.cc/nz7whH0m/ubuntu-screwed.gif) gif. The problem was that it used to turn pink and brighter (and eventually plain white) wherever I used to move my cursor.
5. I used to take screen shot with Ctrl+Shift+PrintScreen key shortcut of Ubuntu. It used to turn the cursor to plus (+) sign which I can drag it across screen and then do Ctrl+V wherever desired. While taking screenshot for this post I tried the same but the plus (+) shaped cursor did not appear for long. Then when it appeared, it only appeared when I moved it at the Ubuntu bottom taskbar. So I tried doing normal printscreen to image and open that image in Kolourpaint app. But while doing that I realized left side menus of open Image dialog of Kolourpaint app are unresponsive:
   [image]
   (I fixed it by running `r` command in Alt+F2 Ubuntu command box by
   re-running whole UI)

When I turned Off hardware accerations on all browsers all of their issues seem to have resolved. Also seems that the issue after turning pink and white when cursor is moved was with browsers only as I tried only Edge browser as can be seen in gif. That issue was originally gone after restart. But if it was browser only, then I guess it will go away with hardware accelearation Off. Now major issues (point 3 and 4) are fixed, but points 1, 2 and 5 are / might still be there. How do I fix this?

It seems that some hardware driver related thing might have gone wrong. Is there anyway (any such thing as) to turn the graphics / hardware acceleration off Ubutnu-wide and not just in browsers. Is there any other solution? I have Lenovo Yoga C940 14IIL with Intel Iris graphics and not external graphics driver.

**Update**

I forgot to mention that used to slow down when I extended screen to second monitor through USB-C Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207777/graphical-glitches-using-ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-13-2019-laptop/1207788#1207788 I need this for a Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] card. If it works, then let us know and upvote the answer.

Comment: I just added the update that it used to slow down after adding second monitor.

Comment: Do not post this as an "Update" to the other text. This is crucial information, so put it up and front so people do not need to be misled until they have read through.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue with auto-updated Intel graphics drivers. I uninstalled them with command

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279996/ubuntu-20-4-lts-upgrade-graphical-glitches), rebooted the machine and everything got fixed!