# Ubuntu 20.04 VGA is not accelerated with nvidia gpu

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on lenovo yoga slim7 laptop which is loaded with nvidia 350M graphics card.
I add ppa and apt installed nvidia-470 driver which is the latest one however GPU does not seem to be utilized for desktop GUI rendering as I feel delays in any screen input even for terminal.

Here is what the settings > About page look like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbpf5.png)

I checked lspci to find VGA controller but could not find nvidia here.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
```

and only find

```
$ lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)  
30:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce MX350] (rev a1)
```

Additional info

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3a34
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
30:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce MX350] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP107M [GeForce MX350]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Is there a way to enable GPU for VGA controller?

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command to your question. Format text uisng `{}` icon.

Comment: Sorry I just revised the format and added additional info you requested.

Comment: So, the driver is installed I see no problems. You have dual graphics. You can switch to Nvidia in Nvidia X Server app.

Comment: I know the driver is installed but I feel delays in every keyboard input in the screen. Can you explain how to use nvidia x server app?

Comment: Keyboard delays are not related. Run the app and see what is there. You can switch adapters there.

Comment: My other laptop which works great without any problem shows lspci | grep 'VGA' as below.
  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f11 (rev a1)

Comment: So... why do you think keyboard delays are related to Nvidia?

Comment: well keyboard delay is just a symptom of GUI delays. I see slow in refreshing GUI whenever a new tab is clicked or partial updates and tearing. It seems like there is no graphics acceleration. And I see nvidia is only used for 3D and not for VGA. 
Maybe re-installing xserver-xorg-video-intel solve this issue?

Comment: reinstalling anything will not solve anuthing

Comment: Well actually it did the trick! Reinstalling xserver driver for intel finally able to accelerate GUI and make it a lot faster but not smoother. Now I see little graphical noise all over the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a discussion regarding this issue here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1937072

Problem is caused by PSR in ubuntu.
To disable PSR, open /etc/default/grub with editor
and add below line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=0"
```

If there is GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, add # in front of the line.

Save and exit.

Enter "$ sudo update-grub" and "reboot"

To check if PSR is enabled by entering

```
$ sudo cat /sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr
```

should return “0” zero.

Formerly, it gave me “-1”.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue here was about some nvidia drivers do not provide any acceleration for VGA and only handle 3D graphics.
Without telling intel driver to accelerate the VGA, all GUI environment is not accelerated by anything.
So I have to manually tell intel driver do the thing.

To solve this issue, I created xorg.conf file under /etc/X11/
and add below

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "intel"
    Screen 1 "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option      "DRI"   "1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

This setting enables VGA acceleration using intel driver and makes the graphics a lot faster.

> Note that "Option      "DRI"   "1" " is added

<s>However, this does not solve all the issue as I see some weird dots all over the desktop and screen tearing exactly like this
[Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)</s>