# Every time I turn on computer green square shows over wallpaper Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, 20.04, visual-artifacts

recently I upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 LTS. Everything is working fine except some minor display issue. Display resolution if good but every time I turn on my computer or restart it, there is square green patches or vertical green lines over the wallpaper. Also, the moment I change the wallpaper it disappears. I don't what the exact issue is? I am using HP notebook.
Below I have attached what it looks like.

[image: Square Green patch]

Comment: Wow, _this_ looks rather similar [to _that_](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238156).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy graphics after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Yes, It helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'm using Nvidia-prime with "On Demand" profile, so in fact still using the Intel graphic card for the desktop.

Solution was to remove the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver which is [discouraged for hardware from 2007 and newer. Better to uninstall this driver and let the system use its builtin modesetting driver instead.](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/xserver-xorg-video-intel)

This can be done by the following command:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I found this solution there (as suggested in the comments by 0xC0000022L and karel):
[Ubuntu 20.04 graphics driver problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238156/ubuntu-20-04-graphics-driver-problem)