# Wavy screen OR green rectangles on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have lenovo ideapad 310 and I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on it.
I have installed nvidia, so according to settings I have:
`NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 920MX] / NVIDIA GeForce 920...` as my graphics.

When I want to scroll in browsers it looks wavy. The wavy screen on chrome and chromium is much worse than firefox.

I used [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231443/1556608) and I add that file to **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d** directory and the wavy screen disappears.
But another problem occurs. Whenever I reboot I see green rectangles.
I used [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242088/1556608) to solve the issue but again I have a wavy screen.

How could I solve both problems?

Comment: Could you please provide the driver origin used for u device?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean exactly but when I run `neofetch` command I receive this result : 
GPU: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics  
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX 
In the additional drivers I chose `nvidia-driver-470` which is marked as tested for installation.

Comment: Ok, so you are using nvidia-driver-470, Have you tried with `nouveau`?

Comment: I changed to `nouveau` from Software & Update GUI then rebooted and unfortunately there was no good change. @MatthiasLenmher

Comment: could you provide more than "no good change" info?

Comment: As i can see, you are under hybrid graphic config... u must have 2 gpu (intel/nvidia), if you have some graphical issues, you considerely change drivers. Also, you are running under IGD or DIS device?

Comment: I mean after installing `nouveau` and also other versions like `nvidia-driver-418` I have a tearing window. If I open a folder or drag a folder layout or ... the windows is tearing. In firefox if I use the mouse wheel to scroll it is OK, but if I drag the scroll bar then the screen is wavy or tearing. In chrome and chromium it is much worse even scrolling by the mouse wheel is terrible.

Comment: This [solution](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/fix-screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04-optimus-laptops/) is good and I don't see tearing window while I scroll by mouse wheel on chrome. But it is not perfect I mean If I double click on a folder tearing screen appears again. I read somewhere ubuntu 21 does not have tearing window!

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help but I don't know meaning of DIS and IGD device.

Comment: I am thinking to use `bumblebee` or not.

Comment: i'm not a "let software's wizard make all magic for me" devote =), i can't suggest something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I chose `intel` for graphic card instead of `on-demand`, `nvidia` or `nouveau` and now the problem is solved and I do not have wavy screen.
I hope this answer helps someone else.